# react increment decrement counts issue

Tags: reactjs

```
  increment: function() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    }); 
     console.log(this.state.counter)
  },

  decrement: function(){
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter - 1
    });
     console.log(this.state.counter)
  },

  calFun: functin(){
     this.state.counter * 5; // incorrect
  }

  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <div id='counter'>{this.state.counter}</div> 
      <button onClick = {this.increment}> +1 </button> 
      <button onClick = {this.decrement}> -1 </button> 
     </div>
  }
```

`{this.state.counter}` output number shows correctly, however, `console.log` always counts `one more` e.g if I click `increment` twice, console shows `0` and `1`, then I click `decrement` console shows `2`, `1` which caused my program runs incorrectly.  What I am expecting is  `1`, `2`, then `1`,`0`

how to have `real-time` correct increment/decrement counts?

**UPDATE:**

after searching a while I changed to below, now it is working just fine and fast, `componentWillUpdate()` makes `update` a little slow

```
  this.setState({
      counter: ++this.state.counter
  });

 this.setState({
      counter: --this.state.counter
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.setState()` asynchronously updates the value of `this.state`. Because you make your `console.log(this.state)` calls synchronously immediately after calling `this.setState()` the value of `this.state` has not changed yet at this point - you are just logging the current value.

To access and log the updated `this.state`, after the asynchronous update has executed, you can use the [lifecycle hook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) `componentDidUpdate()`

Answer (score 1):

this.setState() is asynchronous method, and it means current state.

So you have two ways to get next state.

1.[react-state-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-state-promise)

2.Use react-component lifecycle methods.

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) / componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `this.setState` works asynchronously.
If you want to have correct console.logs, you should use code like this:

```js
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter - 1
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.counter);
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous